# Redefining Pythons builtin datatypes

Tags: python, list, object, subclass, built-in-types

Is it possible to redefine which object the brackets [] use?

I can subclass the `list` object, but how to I make the interpreter use my subclass in place of the buildin list object? Is it possible?

(I'm pretty sure I'm using the wrong terms for the question- feel free to edit)

```
>>> class mlist(list):
...     def __init__(self):
...         list.__init__(self)
...     def __getitem__(self, item):
...         return list.__getitem__(self, item) * 2
... 
>>> testlist = mlist()
>>> testlist.append(21)
>>> testlist[0]
42
>>> list = mlist() # maybe setting the 'list' type will do it?
>>> testlist = []
>>> testlist.append(21)
>>> testlist[0]
21                 # Nope
>>>
```

I don't have a practical use for this- just curious.

Comment: One way (just for curiosity :)) will be by manipulating the byte code by changing `BUILD_LIST` to `LOAD_GLOBAL 'mlist' CALL_FUNCTION ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the code after you've run the code you posted

```
>>> testlist = list()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'mlist' object is not callable
```

Now, determine the type using the code I've posted

```
>>> type([])
<type 'list'>
>>> type(list)
<class '__main__.mlist'>
>>> type(testlist)
<type 'list'>
```

it seems that `[]` creates `list`, instead of `mlist`, it looks strange :S

**Update**

I checked the bytecode generated using `dis`, and the code below was generated

```
>>> import dis # python's disassembler

>>> def code1():
...     return []
...
>>> dis.dis(code1)
  2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 RETURN_VALUE

>>> def code2():
...     return list()
...
>>> dis.dis(code2)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

It appears that `list` will invoke whatever is assigned to it, while `[]` will be converted to `BUILD_LIST` bytecode. It appears that `[]` is not translated to `list`, hence `[]`'s behavior is stucked to creating list.

**Update 2**

Python class can be updated

```
>>> class NewList(list):
...     pass
...
>>> a = NewList()
>>> a.append(23)
>>> a[0]
23
>>> def double_getitem(self, key):
...     return list.__getitem__(self, key) * 2
...
>>> NewList.__getitem__ = double_getitem
>>> a[0]
46
```

Well, except for builtin classes, like list

```
>>> list.__getitem__ = double_getitem
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'list'
```

Comment: right- my question is can It be changed so `[]` creates my object? Can you seamlessly replace the `list` datatypes with your own subclass?

Comment: very interesting- great to know

Answer (score 7):

The brackets are part of the language. They're used to create lists. It's not possible to redefine that (and not desirable either!).

Comment: Yeah, it could really screw stuff up. It just a curiosity question; I don't think I have a practical use for it.

Comment: It is possible, just very, very difficult.

Comment: @Ignacio, can you explain how? I'm curious too. :-)

Comment: You would have to build your own frontend that would compile the script, walk the AST replacing each list literal with a call to `mlist()`, and then run it.

Comment: @Ignacio: I'd call this building your own language and interpreter on top of Python.  It's not Python any more.

Comment: Well, it still uses all the same facilities Python does. It just adds a processing step in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace list with mlist by using not, as you tried,

```
list = mlist()
```

but simply

```
list = mlist
```

(You might have problems running this in the interpreter, because mlist() calls list() and so on recursively.  But if you put the code that defines mlist in a different scope, such as in a module you import, then it will work.)  Then you can create a new mlist by

```
testlist = list()
```

but interestingly, not by

```
testlist = []
```

which I had thought was syntactically equivalent.  Apparently [ ] is hardcoded to call the built-in list type, rather than whatever object is currently named "list".

Comment: I thought they were as well- hence my curiosity!

Comment: Since it's the compiler that translates [] into BUILD_LIST, as Onesimus points out, then I would say no, you absolutely cannot change the behaviour.  You could rewrite the compiler to change it but then what you would have would be, in some real sense, not Python but a different language "inspired" by Python.

Comment: Yeah- My curiosity relates to what can be done with Python the language itself. If you start messing with the Python code, anything is possible

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.  Most things are possible in software, if you're willing to get sufficiently dirty. :)  It's a bad idea, of course.  If you wrote any software using such a change, it would have a number of problems:

- Readers would be easily confused by your code.  They think they're reading Python, so they think they know what [] means, but oops nope they don't.
- If the scope of the change was global (instead of limited to, say, a single source file) then you would have difficulty combining your software with anyone else's, since you're effectively writing in two different languages.  Other software might break if [] starts returning a different type, even if it's a subclass.
- If the scope of the change is limited, then you may easily end up being confused yourself as you look at different source files with different syntax rules.  If you have data that is operated on by different modules, you may find yourself in a circumstance where your code wants that data in an mlist and some other code wants it in a list and then you're probably sad.

Here's [a CPython extension module](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~exarkun/+junk/evil/view/head:/python/intrinsics.c) from 2003 ([and example](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~exarkun/+junk/evil/view/head:/python/intrinsics_example.py)) which works with Python 2.3.  It very likely needs to be updated to work with more recent versions of Python, but it demonstrates how dirty you need to get for this particular approach.

Another approach is to change things at the level of the grammar.  [Logix](http://logix-language.sourceforge.net/tutorial/8-Logix-from-Python.html) provides tools for this approach.  This involves less C hacking, but brings in an entire new parser and compiler.