# Extending List Datatype in python using subclassing

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, subclassing

I wish to extend the **List** data structure in Python, so that it supports additional methods.

After going through resources in the net, I found **Subclassing** is the way to go about it. I tried that and it worked perfectly, when initialising list using `list()` keyword.

#### But the problem arises when I try to initialise  a list using [ ]

Here is a sample code, to explain the problem :

```py
class CustomList(list):

    def addOne(self):
        self.append(1)
        return self


__builtins__['list'] = CustomList

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = list()
    x.addOne()

    y = []
    y.addOne()
```

Here the variable x works perfectly fine.

However ***when `addOne` is called using variable `y`, it throws the exception*** :

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'list' object has no attribute 'addOne'
```

Please help, how do I get this to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redefining Pythons builtin datatypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217351/redefining-pythons-builtin-datatypes)

Comment: Just check the type of both variables x and y,